# Is it possible to transfer a minecraft world from ps4 to a android phone

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I really would like to have one of my hardest worked on worlds on my phone, and carry it every where,

Answer (score 0):

No, because Microsoft owns the pocket edition, and sony doesn't, meaning you cant transfer them safely, you could, but it's not safe and could break you mc.